# position: fixed caused element to be wider than browser

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why position:fixed cause the element to be wider than the browser or other content on the page and causing horizontal scrolling?

Here is the code
HTML

```
<header>
     this is a header
</header>

<div class="container">
     this is a container
</div>
```

CSS

```
 header {
      width: 90%;
      height: 100px;
      background: blue;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 100;
 }

.container {
     width: 90%;
     height: 500px;
     background: red;
     position: relative;
     z-index: -2;
}
```

Here is a link to the codepen http://codepen.io/colbydodson/pen/wcgua

Comment: This blog post (http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/), while old and not addressing your problem directly, might be worth a look for others having problems with fixed positioning on mobile devices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Width* is differently applied to `relative` and `fixed` elements, the ancestors `margin`, and the style property that are parent-inheritable in respect to their `position` property.

The `body` tag will have its default User Agent Style Sheet **8px margins** (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

`header` 90% width, being *fixed*, **without** any `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` value will be positioned to the nearest available place but will inherit the *original* document/viewport size, making it in reality 90% wide, but positioned at the 10px 'body' margin offset.
To test, add `top:0; left:0;` for the *fixed* `header` http://jsbin.com/ETAqADu/1/edit

---

`.container` being a block-level DIV element set to `relative` position, will be 90% width of the available parent usable width, which is the `body` innerWidth (not counting the 10 + 10 *px* margins on the X axis)

**Unwanted result**:
logically `header` will be 20px wider than `.container` because position fixed moves your element out of `body` flow.

**Fix**:
control your parent (`body`) element default margin by setting to 0

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

Or a small but heavy **CSS reset** like:

```css
/* QuickReset */
*, *::before, *::after { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Read also [CSS Box Model - Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Comment: Thank you sir. Great answer and explanation!

Answer (score 11):

I was having a similar problem only on mobile. Despite having no margins, borders, padding on any of the parents, my fixed element was still wider than the viewport, and I didn't have the option of using `width: auto`.

If you're willing to not support IE8 and below, you can use

```
width: 100vw
```

[Can I use Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Note that this solution does not work for both mobile and desktop since vw includes the size of any scrollbars.  So if there is a scrollbar on desktop then this will still cause the header to be wider than the body element on the page.  It does however, work for mobile.

Comment: The solution that I have found is to use: width: 100%; max-witdh: 100vw;

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is fine but in my case, I was seeing a fixed header that was wider than the rest of the page **only on a mobile device**. It happened to be caused by some element in the footer that had a `width` in pixels wider (`width: 750px` in my case) than the viewport of the browser.

If you want to know if some element on your page is causing this problem for you? Just open your browser console and remove some elements further down. At some point, you may notice the header becoming the correct width again. Chances are that the element you just removed or some element in it has a `width` in pixels wider than the viewport of the browser.

The solution, in that case, is to either set that element to a lesser width or make it [flexible](https://flexbox.help/).

Answer (score 1):

By default the body tag have margin. 
Try this in your stylesheet:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `position:fixed` behave as the element is detached from document, and placed in the nearest top/left corner of the document, adding default body's margin. That's why it will take the same amount of space, as your second div, if you reset `body` margin.

Comment: For this case you mean `position: fixed;` not *static*.

Answer (score 0):

As Salaw mentioned, using `body { margin: 0; }` will solve the issue, since `<body>` has default margin/padding (depending on the browser). `position: fixed;` removes an element completely from the flow of the document and makes it relative only to the viewport, while `position: relative;` does not.

Given this fact, and given that `width: 90%` means "make this element take up 90% of parent element's available space", and given that the parent of a `fixed` element is the viewport while the parent of this `relative` element is the body with its margin, you have the discrepancy in sizes.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/exzpC