# though #navbar width is 100% and also box-sizing has been set, navbar is little bit wider than body at right side,why?#navbar fixed and width is 100%

Tags: html, css

```css
#navbar{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
    background-color:darksalmon;
    font-size: 25px;
    word-spacing: 25px;
    font-weight: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}  
nav>a{
    color: rgb(2, 66, 2);
    width: 100%;
}
#welcome-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

 h2{
     text-align: center;
     font-family: monospace;
     color: navy;
     text-decoration: black;
     font-size: 50px;
 }
h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
 h3{
     font-family: monospace;
     font-size: 25px;
 }
 
main{
    padding-top: 20PX;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            portfolio
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="project-5-sample.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <a href="#welcome-section">About</a>
            <a href="#projects">Work</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <section id="welcome-section">
                <h1>Hi! I am Kishor</h1>
                <h3>A Beginners</h3>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

though #navbar width is 100% and also box-sizing has been set, navbar is little bit wider than body at right side...why????? i face this when i set position fixed for #navbar, when i fixed navbar box-sizing not working..why? what is solution when fixed navbar and width 100% are mandatory????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [position: fixed caused element to be wider than browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556014/position-fixed-caused-element-to-be-wider-than-browser)

Comment: Your example does not have the problem you describe.

Comment: Make you sure you do not have any margin in body: `body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: @Dario, you were faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to your stylessheet. This will remove the white space around the body element which is addded by default.